# jQuery - Calc height with variable

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to use calc with jQuery? I was trying something like the below but it doesn't seem to be valid. Does anyone know the correct way to do this please?

```
var h = $('.mydiv').height();

$('.shopping-cart-table-container').css({ height: 'calc(100% - ' h')'});
```

Comment: HTML code please?

Comment: Is calc a valid css argument?  Cause as far a jQuery is concerned, you are just giving css a string.

Comment: Why do you need html?

Comment: Any CSS directive that the browser understands, you can also set with jQuery. The issue here seems to be superfluous `'`s

Comment: superfluous `'` and probably you also need to add `px` as units. Otherwise your code looks good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you have a little syntax error.

```
$('.shopping-cart-table-container').css( { height: 'calc(100% - ' + h + 'px)' } );
```

You can also use the new template-string format using backticks:

```
$('.shopping-cart-table-container').css( { height: `calc(100% - ${h}px)` } );
```

**//update:** Remember, that jQuerys `height` function returns pixels without units, so you need to add it as well in your css statement.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing!!! I was looking for days about these simple solution. Thank you very much! Below I show my code that have some changes but the objetive is the same.

---

JS

```
var h = $('.alturainputs').height();

        $('.dynamic-height').DataTable( {
            "scrollY":        'calc(100vh - 350px - ' + h + 'px)',/*card-title-wrap bar-info height*/
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":         true
        } );
```

---

HTML part 1

Assinatura
                                                                     
                                                                  
                                                                   
                                                                     Assinatura

---

HTML part 2

First name
                                    Last name
                                    Position
                                    Office
                                    Age
                                    Start date
                                    Salary
                                    Extn.
                                    E-mail
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Tiger
                                    Nixon
                                    System Architect
                                    Edinburgh
                                    61
                                    2011/04/25
                                    $320,800
                                    5421
                                    t.nixon@datatables.net

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.